# How to roughly find the function of the following graph?

Tags: calculus, interpolation

Given a graph of function as follows.

[image]

- $f(0)=2$
- $f(\pm 1)=0$
- $f(\pm 2)=-1$ is the local minimum value
- $f(x)\to 0$ when  $x\to \pm \infty$
- $f(\pm 4)\approx -10\%=-0.1$

## Attempt

With the help of Wolfram Mathematica, I estimated the function as follows.

$$
f(x)=\frac{16 \left(1-x^2\right)}{ x^4 \sqrt{2} +2\left(5-2 \sqrt{2}\right) x^2+8}
$$

[image]

It is hard to adjust the $f(\pm 4)\approx -10\%$ and the local minimum.

## Question

How to roughly find the function of the following graph?

Comment: $-10\%$ of what?

Comment: @enzotib: of $1.0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take
$$
f(x)=\frac{2(1-x^2)}{1+a x^2+bx^4+cx^6}
$$
and the conditions lead to the values:
$$
a=\frac{35}{16},\quad b=-\frac{21}{32},\quad c=\frac{27}{256}
$$
so simplifying
$$
f(x)=\frac{512(1-x^2)}{256+560x^2-168x^4+27x^6}
$$
[image]